# How to complete one vector to create a basis of a certain subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I have a subspace of $R^3$ that its basis is the vector $(0,1,1)$.
I want to add vectors to it, such that they will create a basis of a subspace, that is equal to the subspace that its basis is consisted from the 2 vectors: $(2,1,0)$ and $(-2,0,1)$

(I hope it is clear). I forgot the technique how to do it?

Comment: You can add the vector $(2,1,0)$. Or, you can add the vector $(-2,0,1)$. Or, you can add any linear combination of those two vectors, so long as it doesn't turn out to be a scalar multiple of $(0,1,1)$.

Comment: How do you know it? What is the method to find it?

Comment: Your subspace is 2-dimensional. Any two linearly independent vectors form a basis.

Comment: @GerryMyerson. Maybe I do not fully understand the question but it seems to me that the new subspace is R^3 itself. Or a new subspace spanned by (2,1,0) and (−2,0,1) is intended but then I do not see the relevance of the original subspace.

Comment: ${\bf R}^3$ is 3-dimensional. $\{\,(0,1,1),(2,1,0)\,\}$ has just 2 vectors in it, so the subspace it spans can't possibly be all of ${\bf R}^3$. But it is the same as the subspace with basis $\{\,(2,1,0),(-2,0,1)\,\}$ because you can express the basis elements of each space as linear combinations of the basis elements of the other. Clearing up your misconceptions about vector spaces may take more work than we can do here on m.se --- suggest you hire yourself a tutor and go over the basics.

Comment: Yes, I confused the vector (0,1,1) with the subspace spanned by (0,1,0) and (0,0,1). By the way, thank you for your graceful comment.

Comment: If you understand how things work now, you can post an answer to your question.

Comment: I don't understand the idea generally. I understand it maybe on this specific question, but don't know how to do it in general case